# How can I solve this Issue from Postman POST html error 500?

Tags: python

This is my first bigger project creating a job ad database using Flask, flask-restful.

I tried to create a "post" in postman but it doesn't work. I receive this code in python "run":

```
{'title': 'Internship Cloud Developer', 'describtion': 'Internship for 6 months full-time as Cloud Developer', 'salary': 65000}

127.0.0.1 - - [30/Dec/2022 23:56:06] "POST /jobs HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Program Files (x86)\PythonProject\Flask\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2548, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "F:\Program Files (x86)\PythonProject\Flask\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2528, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "F:\Program Files (x86)\PythonProject\Flask\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_restful\__init__.py", line 271, in error_router
    return original_handler(e)
  File "F:\Program Files (x86)\PythonProject\Flask\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2525, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "F:\Program Files (x86)\PythonProject\Flask\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1822, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "F:\Program Files (x86)\PythonProject\Flask\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_restful\__init__.py", line 271, in error_router
    return original_handler(e)
  File "F:\Program Files (x86)\PythonProject\Flask\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1820, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "F:\Program Files (x86)\PythonProject\Flask\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1796, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
  File "F:\Program Files (x86)\PythonProject\Flask\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_restful\__init__.py", line 467, in wrapper
    resp = resource(*args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\Program Files (x86)\PythonProject\Flask\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\views.py", line 107, in view
    return current_app.ensure_sync(self.dispatch_request)(**kwargs)
  File "F:\Program Files (x86)\PythonProject\Flask\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_restful\__init__.py", line 582, in dispatch_request
    resp = meth(*args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\Program Files (x86)\PythonProject\Flask\resources\job.py", line 25, in post
    description=data['description'],
KeyError: 'description'
```

The get-method worked without any issues.

I looked at the code and the solutions as well but I havent found any difference. I also followed the instructions to install the versions twice but I did the same as in the solutions.

Thank you for your help.
Here is the code:

models\job.py:

```
job_list = []

def get_last_id():
    last_job = 1

    if job_list:
        last_job = job_list[-1].id + 1

    return last_job


class Job:
    def __init__(self, title, description, salary):
        self.id = get_last_id()
        self.title = title
        self.description = description
        self.salary = salary

    @property
    def data(self):
        return {
            "id": self.id,
            "title": self.title,
            "description": self.description,
            "salary": self.salary
        }
```

resources\job.py:

```
from flask import request
from flask_restful import Resource
from http import HTTPStatus
from models.job import Job, job_list


class JobListResource(Resource):

    def get(self):
        data = []

        for job in job_list:
            if job.is_published is True:
                data.append(job.data)

        return {'data': data}, HTTPStatus.OK

    def post(self):
        data = request.get_json()

        print(data)

        job = Job(
            title=data['title'],
            description=data['description'],
            salary=data['salary']
        )

        job_list.append(job)

        #job.data = property from models
        return job.data, HTTPStatus.CREATED
```

app-work.py:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api
from resources.job import JobListResource

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

api.add_resource(JobListResource, "/jobs")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=5000, debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{
    'title': 'Internship Cloud Developer',
    'describtion': 'Internship for 6 months full-time as Cloud Developer',
    'salary': 65000
}
```

This is the problem.  "description" is misspelled as "describtion", so when the code tries to access `data['description']`, that key is not found.